# Validating textarea (each line one record) in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the proper and elegant way to validate textarea field in Laravel 5.3. The textarea field contains many rows and each row is a record inserted to database. How to validate each row ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I use explode function.

```
$content_array['code'] = explode(PHP_EOL, $request->codes);

$validator = Validator::make($content_array, [
    'code.*' => 'required|string|max:20',
])->validate();

// Store codes logic ...
```

I created custom validator with prepared array as data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want separate input fields for this kind of functionality?

Anyway, I'd split the input string at newlines, then you can process them line for line

```
$array = explode('\n', $inputString);
// handle array, every index is a line
```